# Nodejs not recognizing string(Input in Japanese)

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, multilingual

I am trying to take an input in Japanese language and pass the value as parameter to another function to retrieve data from the function but whenever I run node app.js it doesn't recognize the input. But in the browser it is working just fine.

So it is accessing data from json `const innerArray = { Name : 'Test', Prefecture: '東京都' }`

While accessing it:

```
let prefectureName = innerArray.Prefecture
console.log(prefectureName)
```

The output is `???`

When I use the input in english it also works. Then I also tried to convert the japanese input into english. then again the same problem remains as it can not read the input.
Can anyone help me regarding this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is only a problem in your log console. Node.js uses UTF-16 internally, so Japanese characters are fully supported.

I'd suggest trying the following:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const innerArray = { Name : 'Test', Prefecture: '東京都' }
fs.writeFileSync("test.json", JSON.stringify(innerArray), "utf8");
console.log("innerArray:", innerArray);
```

Then open test.json in something like Notepad++, you should see the characters rendered correctly.

If I try this example in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), the output is fine too since the console or output font has support for Japanese Characters.

Comment: The thing is right now its under development so I am creating the input of json object in the same file using another function. 
So I have imported the utf8 and tried converting the value while receiving, its not working. `let prefectureName = utf8.encode(innerArray.prefecture)`
Also the value automatically changed itself into `æ�±äº¬éƒ½`

Comment: Okay.. I think something just happened here. If I use `æ�±äº¬éƒ½` it works but if I personally type then the app can not recognize `東京都 => ???`

Comment: The console output's OK also in Webstorm FWIW.

Comment: @O.Jones So, is it an IDE problem ?

Comment: It'll depend on the font used for the program output. For example if I run the script in the Windows command prompt or powershell I'll see ??? for the characters, since the font used does not support them.

Comment: Yes, it's an IDE or console (terminal emulator, cmd.exe, powershell) problem. nodejs correctly emits unicode, but the IDE or console renders incorrectly. As @TerryLennox says, that's because it uses a font without Kanji characters.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation, guys. It helped me understand the problem clearly.